# backbone.js one model being changed by multiple views?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

Okay, I've only started learning backbone.js last night and I have to admit I am a tad baffled at the moment. My scenario is relatively simple, I have one HTML table with an id of #checkout_table. This table has 4 rows. It will always have 4 rows, it will never decrease or increase the number of rows. There are various other form elements on the page which I want to be able to effect the values of the rows. Eventually this will be via ajax, but that doesn't seem important for this example. Here is what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/XYZas/

In the backbone docs it says that, "The general idea is to organize your interface into logical views, backed by models, each of which can be updated independently when the model changes, without having to redraw the page. Instead of digging into a JSON object, looking up an element in the DOM, and updating the HTML by hand, you can bind your view's render function to the model's "change" event — and now everywhere that model data is displayed in the UI, it is always immediately up to date."

Am I on the right track to do this? Is passing around an instance of the CheckoutTable model as a global variable really the right way to do this or would you do it differently?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: A Backbone.Model generally represents data ( like a db instance ). What is a CheckoutTable? What does it do? Will there be multiple CheckoutTables? Will they all have the same properties vat, shipping etc..?

Comment: Like czar mentioned: Model represents your data, Views use your models to render it into HTML for display.  Your app should look more along the lines of this: http://jsfiddle.net/XYZas/2/ Check out this great tutorial: http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/01/27/cloudedit-a-backbone-js-tutorial-by-example/

Comment: Hi guys, both these comments were actually really helpful and provided exactly the information I required. So thanks for your help. 

I think, as I'm making a website and not an app, backbone.js might be overkill and just plain jQuery is probably a better option. When I decide to code an app rather than a website I will definitely use backbone.js.

@rkw if you would like to post your comment as an answer I will accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like czar mentioned: Model represents your data, Views use your models to render it into HTML for display.

Your app should look more along the lines of this: http://jsfiddle.net/XYZas/2

Also, check out this great tutorial: http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/01/27/cloudedit-a-backbone-js-tutorial-by-example/